# Perl script to convert a collection of text into vector representation

Tags: perl

The input file is in UTF8 encoding, each line has the following structure:

```
    C\tTEXT\n
```

where C is a class of documents (several characters), `\t` is a tab, the TEXT is a sequence of characters, `\n` is a newline character.

From each TEXT are removed HTML tags and similar tags, entities, characters that are not letters, and each text is converted to sequence of words, where the order is not important.

From each TEXT is then created vector where individual elements of the vector (attributes) correspond to the words in the text collection, and the values ​​in the vector will depend on the occurrence of the word in the TEXT. These values ​​can be of two types:

```
A - number of occurrences of words (1 or 0) 
B - number of occurrences    of words (0 or more)
```

Last value vector is the class of the document.

If necessary, the words which together have a low (eg, one), the frequency may be removed from all texts.

words that have a small number of characters can also be removed.

```
Example input file:
CLASS    One Class One
CLASS    One Two
2CLASS   two three
CLAS12   three
```

**Example output file:**

These are the parameters of the script(the minimum word length = 1, the minimum occurrence of the word = 1, A)

**Output:**

```
      one two three
CLASS  2   0    0 
CLASS  1   1    0
2CLASS 0   1    1
CLAS12 0   0    1
```

My current code:

Please help me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use encoding 'UTF-8';
use Data::Dumper;

my %vector = ();
my @vectors = ();
my ($string,$word);

open SOURCE, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "source.txt" or die "File does not exist $!\n";

my($class,$hodnota);
while (my $line = <SOURCE>) {
  if($line=~ /^(\w+)\t(.+)\n/){  
    $string =$2; $class = $1;
    $string=~ s/[^a-zA-Z ]//g; 

      for $word ( split " +", $string )
      {
        $vector{$word}++;
      }

      $vector{"class"} = $class;
      push(@vectors, %vector)
   }

}          
    close S;

print Dumper( \@vectors );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```
chomp($line);
if ($line =~ /^(\w+)\t(.+)/){
    my $vector = {};
    my ($class, $string) = ($1, $2);
    for my $word (split /[^a-zA-Z]/, $string) {
        next if length($word) < $some_treshold; # $word is too short
        my $word_lc = lc($word);
        $vector{$word_lc}++;
        $all_words{$word_lc} = 1; # this has to be initialized before main loop, as $all_words = {};
    }
    $vector{"class"} = $class; # hopefully, no words will be "class"
    push(@vectors, %vector)
}
```

When this is done, all used words can be found by `keys %$all_words`. Hopefully, I correctly understood what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $in_data, shift(@ARGV);
my @array_of_hashes_of_hashes=(); 
#used array of hashes_of_hashes because you treated two instances of CLASS differently
#if they could be treated the same, a simple hash of hashes would work fine.

while (<$in_data>)
{  
    if ($_ =~ /^(\w+)\t(.+)\n/)
    {   
        my %temp_hash=();
        my @values=split(/ /,$2);

        foreach (@values)
        {
            $temp_hash{lc($_)}+=1; #so that one and One map to the same key
        }

        push @array_of_hashes_of_hashes, {$1 => \%temp_hash};
    }
}

print Dumper \@array_of_hashes_of_hashes; #just to show you what it looks like
```

I noticed that you did not print the value for `Class` from `CLASS    One Class One`, so if you want to filter that out when you go to print everything.